# What is the most elegant way to display multiple graphs with a common title?

Tags: grid-layouts, labeling

I often seek to display two graphs, side by side, with a common label over them. There is no option for adding a label to `GraphicsRow`, which means, I think, that I need to use `Grid` or `GraphicsGrid` and include a row on top that has `SpanFromLeft` set to allow a graphically defined line of text occupy the entire row.

It seems like a lot of work to do something simple. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use `Labeled`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Possibly more versatile, but you have to mess with text overlapping your plots, but `GraphicsRow` also accepts `Epilog`

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}], Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]}, 
 Spacings -> Scaled[0.4], 
 Epilog -> Inset["Plot Title", Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `PlotRangePadding -> {0, {0, 25}}` could help avoid possible text/plot collisions.

Comment: @ssch Thanks - I figured there was a padding option, but couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: Since PlotLabel broke in v12, I’ve switched over to this approach.

Answer (score 35):

[`GraphicsRow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsRow.html) takes a [`PlotLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotLabel.html) option:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Sin];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLabel -> Cos];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}, PlotLabel -> "Two plots"]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't imagine how I missed this. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelStern Easy to miss since it's not in the GraphicsRow documentation :)

Comment: @Michael Indeed, this is the first time I can recall seeing this, so thank you for asking the question! (+1 of course, ssch)

Comment: As of version 12, this no longer works. Sigh.

Comment: Not in 12.2 either. A pity.

Answer (score 11):

When I need more interface control, I usually do something like this:

```
p1=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi},PlotLabel->Sin,ImageSize->150];
p2=Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,Pi},PlotLabel->Cos,ImageSize->150];
title=Panel[Style["Test Label",White,20],ImageSize->300,Background->Orange,Alignment->Center];
Deploy@Grid[{{title,SpanFromLeft},{p1,p2}},Dividers->Gray,Spacings->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Few additional methods:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 200];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 200];
```

**Labeled**

```
Labeled[Panel@GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}], Style["Label", "Subsubsection"], Top] // Panel
```

[image]

**Panel**

```
Panel[GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}], Style["Label", "Subsubsection"], Top] // Panel
(* same picture *)
```

**Legended**

```
Legended[Panel@GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}], Placed[Style["Label", "Subsubsection"], Top]] // Panel
(* same picture *)
```

**Show with PlotLabel**

```
Show[GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}],  PlotLabel -> Style["Label", "Subsubsection"]] // Panel
```

[image]

Comment: This answer actually seems to be the most versatile.