# Graphicsrow title

Tags: graphics, labeling

I made the following graphic with *Mathematica 9.0*:

[image: GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot[]ĹistLinePlot[]]]

Does anybody know how to put a title on the top of the whole graph? (not in each single plot).

Basically I used

```
GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot[]ListLinePlot[]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32919/7167)

Answer (score 2):

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 200];

Framed[
 Column[
  {
   Style["Sinus", Darker@Blue, Bold, 16],
   GraphicsRow[{p, p}]
   },
  Alignment -> Center],
 FrameMargins -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: I've already labeled the plot using 'PlotLabel', but I'd like to know how to avoid too much white space between the title and the plots.

Comment: I tried using Epilog and the label appear where I want, but how can I change the style/size/color of the title?.Thanks