# Intelligently formatting PDFs

Tags: output-formatting

I'm exporting a Grid[] to a PDF. It's *working,* but it's real ugly. Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Possibly the first problem is the reason I posted a picture of (rather than sharing) the PDF: as you can see, it's a single page, with about 3x6 plots, yet it's somehow **16MB.** Since normal PNG files of reasonable size are ~50kb or so, I'm guessing that the file is so huge because it's doing something like writing each data point to the file or something, so has way more information than is useful or even possible to really see.

So, my first question is, how can I do this so the file isn't enormous?

My second question is about the formatting. Right now, it's obviously very ugly: The titles and axes labels of the plots are being cut off, the tic mark labeling is crammed together, etc. It's hard to give an example of the code because it's quite big, but here's a contrived example that will show what I mean:

```
Grid[Table[
  Table[Plot[a*x^b, {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     "What a long and interesting and certainly necessary title for a \
plot of the function " <> ToString[ax*b]], {a, 2, 3}], {b, 4, 5}]]
```

So, how can I make it wrap around automatically, and resize so it's not taking up a ton of space?

Any other tips for this would be welcome as well! I'm just doing it naively, the way it was easiest to.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you are using Acrobat, which does have an "Optimize PDF" functionality, and that can cut down the size quite a lot. Have you tried this?

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica is notorious for producing gigantic PDFs.

Comment: Also, this does not really answer your question, but inserting explicit \n into the PlotLabel text does introduce a newline. Not automatic, but does work.

Comment: @IgorRivin, thanks, but I don't really want to have to do that each time I produce a PDF. One option (I think) would be to make my program export all my plots as .png's, then Import those and put them into the PDF, that might make it smaller. But it'd be really annoying even if it does work. I know I can use \n but it'd be nicer if it was automatic. Thank you!

Comment: You could `Rasterize` the `Grid` prior to exporting to PDF: `Grid[...]//Rasterize`. Also, recommend that `ToString` include `TraditionalForm`: `ToString[a x^b, TraditionalForm]`.

Comment: Well, re size, you _can_ automate it, using, say: https://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/wiki/InstallationInstructions

Comment: Why do you need to have your graphics as PDF? Is it intended for presentation or for publication purposes? Your actual goal is crucial for providing a *good* answer.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? I have been told by tech support that version 10 produces much smaller PDFs. Another option is to use NotebookPrint[] and set your default printer to something like PDFCreator.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I actually don't need to use PDF I guess -- I just defaulted to that. Now I'm trying Rasterize[] and Export[] to .png. The files it produces aren't massive, but it has its own problems. I'm just trying to make a large presentation for a projector.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino, I'm using MM 10.

Answer (score 9):

Part a response, Because you do not show additional information and do not describe the problem with the code, I show one approach.

First we construct some helpers :

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
siz1 = 250;
siz2 = 500;
tex1 = "What a long and interesting and certainly necessary title for \
a panel of functions.";
title = Panel[Style[tex1, Black, 16, LineIndent -> 0], 
   ImageSize -> siz2, Background -> White, Alignment -> Left];
tex2 = "This is another text without meaning and is only here to \
prove place.";
caption = 
  Panel[Style[tex2, Black, 10, LineIndent -> 0], ImageSize -> siz1, 
   Background -> White, Alignment -> Center];

p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotLabel -> Sin, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {caption, None}}, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> siz1, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotLabel -> Cos, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {caption, None}}, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> siz1, PlotStyle -> Blue];
p3 = Plot[Tan[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotLabel -> Tan, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {caption, None}}, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> siz1, PlotStyle -> Darker[Green]];
p4 = Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotLabel -> "Sin, Cos, Tan", Frame -> True];
```

The strategy to combine plots with text I got from this [QnA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32919/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-display-multiple-graphs-with-a-common-title) (thanks @Murta and @kguler)

```
dg1 = Deploy@
  Grid[{{title, SpanFromLeft}, {p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}, Dividers -> Gray, 
   Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

To combine multiple plots try;

```
ex1 = Grid[{{dg1, dg1}, {dg1, dg1}, {dg1, dg1}}, Spacings -> {1, 2}, 
  Frame -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

For export and fine tuning:

```
Export["myFig-.pdf", ex1]
Export["myFig-IR.pdf", ex1, ImageResolution -> 256]
Export["myFig-Ras.pdf", ex1, "AllowRasterization" -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Full, ImageResolution -> 512]
```

The file size on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014) is about 158 KB.

Comment: So cool and so interesting!

Answer (score 4):

The file is gigantic because Mathematica is putting vector objects in the file in an inefficient way, meaning a LOT of vector objects, fonts, etc, as you suspect.

The best procedure is to generate the page as an image, save the image then add the image to the PDF. This loses the capability to make the PDF page scalable, but you probably don't care about that.

You can generate an image by using `Rasterize` or `CopyToClipboard[Rasterize[...]]`. Taking a screen shot has the same effect (assuming the whole image fits on your screen).

If scalability is important to you (for example, you want a reader to be able to magnify one of the plots with no loss of resolution), then one possible trick is to use LaTeX. Generate the LaTaX code for the output cell and then manually massage the LaTeX code to eliminate any obvious inefficiencies, then render it as a PDF using the LaTeX publishing system. To make the LaTeX closely match the Mathematica output will probably take a significant amount of editing and require knowledge of LaTeX syntax, so you don't want to get into this unless scalability is pretty important.

*** Worst Case Scenario ***

If all else fails you can do a screen shot (Alt-Print Screen on Windows). Note that the Window menu in Mathematica has a "Magnification" choice, so you can blow up your image to any size. If the image does not fit on the screen, take images piecemeal, then stitch them together in an image editing program like Photoshop, Gimp, Inkscape, etc.

Comment: I believe my suggestion in the comment to Optimize PDF in acrobat is much more time efficient.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I'm doing this method now, but I'm running into some trouble. First, when doing Rasterize, it was cramming the numbers on the tickmarks of my plots together, so they were overlapping and looking messy. I think I managed to make this better by fiddling with the Rasterize options (currently using RasterSize -> 1000, ImageSize -> 2000), but then when I do Export[] to a .png, it makes the .png have really bad resolution. What can I do?

Comment: All I really want to do is have a bitmap picture of what Grid[] pops out, so why is Rasterize messing around with the fonts and sizes and formatting? Can't it just take the output of Grid[] and essentially 'flatten' it? Thank you!

Comment: @FdotFloss As posted in my answer you can always fall back to screenshots. I have noticed that in some cases Rasterize does not always give exact reproduction of screen renderings.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified why do you actually need to have your graphics in the PDF format and why (actually) the 16 Mb size is a problem for you. I'll only comment about the appearance.

From your description I can conclude that you have generated a nice-looking graphics inside of the *Mathematica*'s FrontEnd but when you `Export` it as PDF your graphics does not look as it was inside of the FrontEnd: it is damaged. The most probable reason for this is that the FrontEnd by default displays everything in the `"Working"` style environment while `Export` to PDF uses by default the `"Printout"` style environment. So the first thing to try in such cases is to `Export` your graph in the `"Working"` style environment. One way to do this is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093783/590388):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

After evaluating the above, `Export` your graph again. For reverting to the default behavior, just evaluate:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout"]
```

It is hard to say more without an example code and with such a little information on what your are actually trying to do.