# How to label a GraphicsGrid?

Tags: plotting

I am constructing a GraphicsGrid from a set of plots. Is there an easy way to add an overall label for the whole grid?

Comment: `Labeled[GraphicsGrid[...], something]`? See [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html).

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [... multiple graphs with a common title](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32919/125)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `PlotLabel`:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[Table[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {k, 4}], 2], 
 PlotLabel -> "Insert Label Here"]
```

[image]

Comment: This method no longer appears to work in Mathematica 12.0.

Comment: Try using `Show[ GraphicsGrid[ ...], PlotLabel-> "Label"]`

Comment: Is there a way to have a label for the top two and another for the two in the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

```
Panel[GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {k, 4}], 2]], 
 Style["label", "Panel", 16], {{Top, Center}}]
```

[image]

```
Panel[GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {k, 4}], 2]], 
 Style["label", "Panel", 16], {{Top, Center}}, 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]